# $q$-Eulerian type B enjoy symmetry

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $(q;q)_n=(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^n)$ with $(q;q)_0:=1$. Define a $q$-exponential by 
$$e(z;q)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{z^n}{(q;q)_n}.$$
There is a notion of $q$-Eulerian polynomials, see [the reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4941.pdf). I like to introduce **$q$-Eulerian polynomial of type B** via the generating function
$$\sum_{n\geq1}B_n(t,q)\frac{z^n}{(q;q)_n}=\frac{(e(z;q)-e(tz;q))(e(tz;q)+te(z;q))}{e(2tz;q)-te(2z;q)}.$$
Now, expand $B_n(t,q)$ as a polynomial 
$$B_n(t,q)=\sum_{k=0}^nB_{n,k}(q)t^k$$
and call $B_{n,k}(q)$ **$q$-Eulerian numbers type B**. Here are the first few terms:
\begin{align} B_1(t,q)&=1+t, \\
B_2(t,q)&=1+(2q+4)t+t^2, \\
B_3(t,q)&=1+(7q^2+7q+9)t+(7q^2+7q+9)t^2+t^3.
\end{align}

> **Claim.** if $a, b\in\Bbb{N}$ and $\alpha=a+b+1$, then the symmetric relation holds:
>   $$\binom{\alpha}a_q+\sum_k\binom{\alpha}k_q2^{\alpha-k}B_{k,b}(q)=
> \binom{\alpha}b_q +\sum_k\binom{\alpha}k_q2^{\alpha-k}B_{k,a}(q).$$

**QUESTIONS:**

(a) I don't have a proof for my claim which seems very true though. Do you?

(b) Is there a combinatorial interpretation for these polynomials $B_n(t,q)$ or the Eulerian numbers $B_{n,k}(q)$? You might be inspired by [the reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4941.pdf).

Comment: I proved (a), but I don't know anything about (b).

Comment: @Nemo: do you like to share your proof?

Comment: Why type B? Is it somehow related to the ABCDEF nomenclature?

Comment: Type B because there are types A & B in the classical literature ($q=1$).

Comment: Could you please provide a link?

Comment: Here is a link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4941.pdf

Comment: Thank you. In that paper, there are polynomials $A^{(r)}$. Are $B$ one of those?

Comment: Wait, why give the same name to two different families: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322848/on-a-certain-1-eulerian-polynomials-of-type-b ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\bf{Step~1}.$ $B_{n,a}(q)=B_{n,n-a}(q)$.

$\it{Proof}$. Write
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\dfrac{B_n(t,q)}{t^{n/2}}\frac{z^n}{(q;q)_n}=\frac{e(z/\sqrt{t};q)-e(z\sqrt{t};q)}{\dfrac{e(2z\sqrt{t};q)}{\sqrt{t}}-\sqrt{t}~e(2z/\sqrt{t};q)}\left(\dfrac{e(z\sqrt{t};q)}{\sqrt{t}}+\sqrt{t}~e(z/\sqrt{t};q)\right).
$$
The rhs is symmetric under $t\to 1/t$, so $\dfrac{B_n(t,q)}{t^{n/2}}$ is also symmetric:
$$
\dfrac{B_n(t,q)}{t^{n/2}}=t^{n/2}{B_n(1/t,q)}.\tag{1}
$$
We know that $B_n(t,q)=B_{n,0}t^0+...$ starts with the power $t^0$. Due to $(1)$ this means that the highest power of $t$ in the polynomial $B_n(t,q)$ is $n$, and $B_{n,a}(q)=B_{n,n-a}(q)$ as required.

$\bf{Step~2}.$ $\displaystyle{\binom{\alpha}a_q+\sum_k\binom{\alpha}k_q2^{\alpha-k}B_{k,b}(q)=
\binom{\alpha}b_q +\sum_k\binom{\alpha}k_q2^{\alpha-k}B_{k,a}(q)},~ a,b,\in \mathbb{N},~a+b+1=\alpha.$

$\it{Proof}$.
According to q-binomial theorem $e(z;q)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{z^n}{(q;q)_n}=\frac{1}{(z;q)_\infty}$. Now we equate the coefficients of $z^n$ in both sides of 
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{l\geq0}\frac{(2tz)^l}{(q;q)_l}-t\sum_{l\geq0}\frac{(2z)^l}{(q;q)_l}\right)\cdot\sum_{k\geq1}B_k(t,q)\frac{z^k}{(q;q)_k}={(e(z;q)-e(tz;q))(e(tz;q)+te(z;q))}\\
=\left(\sum_{l\geq0}\frac{z^l}{(q;q)_l}-\sum_{l\geq0}\frac{(tz)^l}{(q;q)_l}\right)\left(\sum_{l\geq0}\frac{(tz)^l}{(q;q)_l}+t\sum_{l\geq0}\frac{z^l}{(q;q)_l}\right)
\end{align}
and obtain
$$
\sum _{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}_q\frac{B_k(t,q) \left(t^{n-k}-t\right) }{2^{k-n}}-\sum _{k=1}^n \left(1-t^k\right) \left(t^{n-k}+t\right) \binom{n}{k}_q=0.
$$
The coefficient of $t^{a+1}$ in the above formula is (note that for $a\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a+1\neq1$ and for $b=n-a-1\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a+1\neq n$, so the 'boundary' terms with $t$ and $t^n$ don't make any contribution in the formula below)
$$
-\sum _{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}_q \frac{B_{k,a}(q) }{2^{k-n}}+\sum _{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}_q\frac{B_{k,a+1+k-n}(q)}{2^{k-n}}+\binom{n}{a}_q-\binom{n}{b}_q=0.
$$
Finally, taking into account $B_{k,a+1+k-n}(q)=B_{k,k-b}(q)=B_{k,b}(q)$ we have
$$
\binom{n}{b}_q+\sum _{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}_q \frac{B_{k,a}(q) }{2^{k-n}}=\binom{n}{a}_q+\sum _{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}_q\frac{B_{k,b}(q)}{2^{k-n}}.
$$

Comment: Step 1 was proved in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.4045.pdf as well. I'll look into the rest.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan , what logic did lead you to this conjecture?

Comment: I tried generalizing classical symmetrical relations. There's already one such q-analogue for type A by Guo-Niu Han.

Comment: I checked the proof. Correct.