# On a certain $(-1)$-Eulerian polynomials of type $B$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $(q)_n=(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^n)$ with $(q)_0:=1$. Define a $q$-exponential by
$$e_q(z)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{z^n}{(q)_n}.$$
There is a notion of $q$-Eulerian polynomials of type $A$, see [the reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4941.pdf). I like to introduce **$q$-Eulerian polynomial of type B** via the generating function
$$\sum_{n\geq1}B_n(t,q)\frac{z^n}{(q)_n}
=\frac{(e_q(z)-e_q(tz))\cdot(e_q(tz)+te_q(z))}{e_q(2tz)-te_q(2z)}.$$
Now, expand $B_n(t,q)$ as a polynomial
$$B_n(t,q)=\sum_{k=0}^nB_{n,k}(q)t^k$$
and call $B_{n,k}(q)$ **$q$-Eulerian numbers type B**. The first few terms are:
\begin{align} B_1(t,q)&=1+t, \\
B_2(t,q)&=1+(2q+4)t+t^2, \\
B_3(t,q)&=1+(7q^2+7q+9)t+(7q^2+7q+9)t^2+t^3.
\end{align}
Here is an earlier [MO problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252156/q-eulerian-type-b-enjoy-symmetry). This time, I'm interested in a specialized aspect of it. For instance, $B_n(t,1)$ become the ordinary Eulerian polynomials of type $B$ whose coefficients are listed at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A060187). On the other hand, the polynomials $B_n(t,-1)$ do not appear anywhere. You may look at the first few of these: $B_1(t,-1)=1, B_2(t,-1)=1+t, B_3(t,-1)=1+2t+t^2$,
$$B_4(t,-1)=1+9t+9t^2+t^3 \qquad\text{and} \qquad
B_5(t,-1)=1+12t+22t^2+12t^3+t^4.$$

> **QUESTION 1.** Is there some interpretation of the coefficients in $B_n(t,-1)$?
>
> **QUESTION 2.** Can you provide a proof for the unimodality of $B_n(t,-1)$?