# q-analogs of eulerian polynomials

Tags: reference-request

Let
$$S_k(t)=(1-x)(1-qx)\dots(1-q^k x)\sum_{n\geq0}{(1+q+\dots+q^n)^k x^n}$$
be a q-analog of Carlitz's identity. I look for references where the properties of these Eulerian polynomials are studied.

Comment: This seems different from the two $q$-analogues, given https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4941.pdf and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322848/on-a-certain-1-eulerian-polynomials-of-type-b

Comment: There are some lines missing from the question. I don't know whether this is a problem with my computer or with MO.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: still not good.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: for some reason it is okay now.

Comment: This is the joint distribution of DES and MAJ on the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$. I don't know, however, where your formula first appeared.

Comment: Can you check the basics in http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel//homepage/papers/chow.pdf starting on page 3 and references therein?

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan: Thank you, this is what I looked for.